# Use javaScript file in angular 5 project

Tags: node.js, angular

I am building a web application using Angular 5 and nodejs with express. As both the frontend and the backend are going to run in the same server I want to use my backend javascript functions in the frontend. The solutions that I have found didn't worked for me.

**appController.js**

```
var createApp = function (appData) {
    console.log("App created")
}

exports.createApp = createApp;
```

This is the backend file that I want to use in the front.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript files don't need to export things when used in the front-end. Most of the time, they use global variables. You should go with that.

To add it to your project, add it anywhere you want, and in your Typescript, you can simply use

```
declare var myGlobalVariable: any;

// ...

myGlobalVariable.createApp();
```

Comment: Where I should declare the path to my javascript file?

Comment: Nowhere, if you want to use it in both, this will only be available in production, so you will just need to add it t your index.html file, without the need of declaring the path anywhere

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing. I have a frontend with Angular 5 and a backend serving an API via Express:

If you want to run your Angular frontend and your NodeJS backend on the same server you'll have to build your Angular project and serve the built files with your Express server.

I think I found a tutorial on that – but I can't find it right now...
Instead maybe have a look at my code for the backend:
https://github.com/saitho/ngHashi/blob/next/backend/src/index.ts

In production mode it will serve the files in the folder /backend/dist_frontend by default (apart from the backend routes (/api)). I use a build process (GitLab CI) to move the files I need to the respective place...

Comment: Yes I already did that, but I don't want to use a REST api to comunicate the front and the back. I want to call the methods in the back from the front.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a solution. It would be necessary to modify the tsconfig.json:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  compilerOptions: {
       .....
       allowJS: true,
       ......
  }
}
```